# Вопрос о JavaScript'е , как сделать сочетание клавиш

Tags: javascript, html

Вообщем с одной кнопкой все работает, но не могу разобраться как использовать сочетание клавиш. Например при нажатии на стрелку вправо на клавиатуре, ее keyCode = 39, код для нее такой:

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e1){
  e1 = e1 || window.event;
  if(e1.keyCode === 39) {
    document.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/";
  }
}
```

```html
! <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>название страницы</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

а как например сделать тоже самое, но использовать сочетание клавиш ctrl + стрелка вправо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, код:

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e1){
  e1 = e1 || window.event;
  if(e1.ctrlKey && e1.key === "ArrowDown") {
    document.location.href = "https://yandex.ru/";
  } 
}
```

```html
! <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>название страницы</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```